# Txt file password check batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want my script to compare user input and text from the txt file(test.txt for example)
I know that I can use `type test.txt` but i dont know how to compare it with user input...
Can you help me? thank you...
This is what i have:

```
set choice=
set /p choice=Zvol si heslo slozky:
```

Comment: What does the text file contain? A single line? Multiple lines? Do they all have to match or just one line?

Comment: @Anders One single line.. Sorry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is write the answer to a (temporary) file and compare the files. For example:

```
...
echo %choice% > tempfile.txt
fc tempfile.txt test.txt > NUL
if errorlevel 1 echo answer is different as text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Will ask to enter a password guess and will output to a `results.txt` if found.

```
@echo off
echo Password comparer
set choice=
set /p choice=Enter your password guess:

TYPE test.txt | findstr /m %choice% > results.txt
```